# how to delete from gridview without database "check to determine if the object is null before calling the method"

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

The ff are codes in  my .cs file

```
private void BindGridview(int rowcount)
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   DataRow dr;
   dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Code", typeof(String)));
   dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Course", typeof(String)));
   dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Credit", typeof(String)));

   if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < rowcount + 1; i++)
      {
         dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];
         if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
         }
      }
      dr = dt.NewRow();
      dr[0] = this.cboCourseCode.Text;
      dr[1] = this.txtCourseName.Text;
      dr[2] = this.txtCredit.Text;
      dt.Rows.Add(dr);

   }
   else
   {
      dr = dt.NewRow();
      dr[0] = this.cboCourseCode.Text;
      dr[1] = this.txtCourseName.Text;
      dr[2] = this.txtCredit.Text;
      dt.Rows.Add(dr);
   }

   // If ViewState has a data then use the value as the DataSource
   if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
   {
      GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];
      GridView1.DataBind();
   }
   else
   {
      // Bind GridView with the initial data assocaited in the DataTable
      GridView1.DataSource = dt;
      GridView1.DataBind();
   }
   // Store the DataTable in ViewState to retain the values
   ViewState["CurrentData"] = dt;
}

protected void BindGrid()
{
   GridView1.DataSource = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
   GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
   int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
   DataTable dt = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
   dt.Rows[e.RowIndex].Delete();
   ViewState["dt"] = dt;
   BindGrid();
}

protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      string Code = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
      foreach (Button button in e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.OfType<Button>())
      {
         if (button.CommandName == "Delete")
         {
            button.Attributes["onclick"] = "if(!confirm('Do you want to delete " + Code + "?')){ return false; };";
         }
      }
   }   
}         

protected void cboCourseCode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Populate_Course_Details();
}

protected void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   /*  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Code"), new DataColumn("Course"), new DataColumn("Credit") });
   dt.Rows.Add(this.cboCourseCode.Text, this.txtCourseName.Text, this.txtCredit.Text);           
   ViewState["dt"] = dt;
   BindGrid();*/

   if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
   {
      DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];
      int count = dt.Rows.Count;
      BindGridview(count);
   }
   else
   {
      BindGridview(1);
   }
}
```

My `aspx` file also has this gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass = "Grid" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Course" HeaderText="Course" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Credit" HeaderText="Credit" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When I start to delete, I get this error:

> check to determine if the object is null before calling the method

Comment: What is an 'ff'?  Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Your code is quite confusing. what is your objective please clarify

Comment: ff means following  and dt.Rows[e.RowIndex].Delete(); throws the error

Comment: I use the BindGridview function to fill Gridview1 when I click on the add button. It fill one row at a time from three textboxes. And if I want to delete a particular row, I click on the delete button of that row. It calls OnRowDeleting to delete.  When it reaches dt.Rows[e.RowIndex].Delete(); it throws the error “check to determine if the object is null before calling the method”

Answer (score 0):

**Error Reason**

in OnRowDeleting function you are creating datatable and assigning viewstate["dt"],which doesn't have current data. that's why it shows **Object is Null**

**Solution**

Try This
First make one of the column as data key.consider i want to make "Code" column as datakey.
datakey will help to find specific row to delete

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass = "Grid" runat="server"       OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound" DataKeyNames="Code">
```

After That in .cs code

- create a datatable with currentdata
- make "Code" column as primary key
- find particular code(which you want to delete)using find()
- then delete that row using delete() function
- **Reflect the deletion in viewsate["currentdata"]**
- then bind to gridview

```
protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string code = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

    if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];
         dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["Code"] };

        dt.Rows.Find(code).Delete();
        ViewState["CurrentData"] = dt;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }                       
}
```